# How can I imitate Excel's "Delete and shift left" feature in a python pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I just had a quick question as I have been working on this for a little bit.
I was wondering how I can imitate Excel's delete and shift left for example in a python dataframe. Say I want to delete from cells A1 to G8 in Excel: I'd highlight the cells, right click, and delete, and select the shift left option.

In python, I have attempted to imitate this through the following:

```
for x in range(0,6):
  df.iloc[0:8,x] = df.iloc[0:8,x+6]
  df.iloc[0:8,x+6] = ''
for x in range(6,len(df.columns) - 6):
  df.iloc[0:8,x] = df.iloc[0:8,x+6]
  df.iloc[0:8,x+6] = ''

Where essentially I will take all the rows in the first column, and replace it with all the rows in column G, and repeat for every column after. After the first "shift" is done, in the second loop, I "shift" the entire dataframe (remaining columns) to try and mimic the delete shift left feature of excel.

Results of above code:

Part 1 before delete shift left:

   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10  X11  X12  X13  X14
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3    3    3    3    3    3
1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   4    4    4    4    4    4
2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   5    5    5    5    5    5
3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   6    6    6    6    6    6
4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6  20   20   20   20   20   20
5   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7  30   30   30   30   30   30
6   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8  40   40   40   40   40   40
7   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9  50   50   50   50   50   50

Part 2 after delete shift left:

   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14
0   1   1   3   3   3   3   3   3                       
1   2   2   4   4   4   4   4   4                       
2   3   3   5   5   5   5   5   5                       
3   4   4   6   6   6   6   6   6                       
4   6   6  20  20  20  20  20  20                       
5   7   7  30  30  30  30  30  30                       
6   8   8  40  40  40  40  40  40                       
7   9   9  50  50  50  50  50  50                      

However, I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly or if I will approach any logical errors with this method. I am sort of just improvising as I go and this is what I came up with. I imagine there's a much more elegant and efficient way of doing it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!
```

Comment: What does 'delete & shift left' mean in a DataFrame? Pandas is library for data, but not Excel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'X2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'X3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'X4': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'X5': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'X6': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'X7': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'X8': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'X9': [3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                       'X10': [3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                       'X11': [3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                       'X12': [3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                       'X13': [3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                       'X14': [3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

# How many columns you want to delete    
delete_columns = 6

df = df[df.columns[delete_columns:]].set_axis(df.columns[:len(df.columns[delete_columns:])], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   X1   X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8
0   1   1   3   3   3   3   3   3
1   2   2   4   4   4   4   4   4
2   3   3   5   5   5   5   5   5
3   4   4   6   6   6   6   6   6
4   6   6   20  20  20  20  20  20
5   7   7   30  30  30  30  30  30
6   8   8   40  40  40  40  40  40
7   9   9   50  50  50  50  50  50
```